# Javascript - then function not executing

Tags: javascript

This is my problem

```
const { Client } = require('destiny2');
const client = new Client('apiKey');

window.memberName = function(){

    var pName = document.getElementById('memberName');
    var pId = document.getElementById('memberId');
    var name = document.getElementById('search').value;

    client.getProfile(name, '4')
      .then(data => console.log(data));

    client.getProfile(name, '4').then(
        function(value) { 
            data => pId.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Platform:" + 
              data.profile.platform[1]));
            data => pName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name:" + 
             data.profile.displayName));
        }
    );
}
```

The `client.getProfile(name, '4').then...` Nothing in this function gets executed.

Comment: What is Client?

Comment: This is all calling from an API, .then works fine separately, but when I want to combine multiple ones (to, for example, clear the last entry too) it doesn't execute the function.

`.then(data => pName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name: "+data.profile.displayName)));` 

is what I originally used, but wanted to combine them.

Comment: You are just declaring two anonymous functions , you are never using them though.

Comment: Why don't you return the promise result and put 'catch' on it to examine the error(s)?

Comment: Are you sure this `client.getProfile` actually returns a promise?

Comment: that second function is completely invalid, and is referencing a variable that doesn't exist. `data => console.log(data)` is just shorthand for `function(data) { return console.log(data) }`, so in that second `then` statement you're trying to run two anonymous functions directly inside another anonymous function - on top of that you're accepting `value` as the parameter, then trying to work with a variable called `data` inside there. It looks like a bit of copy and paste hell happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `client.getProfile` call is wrong.

[Promise.prototype.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) expects an `onFulfilled` Function.

```
p.then(onFulfilled[, onRejected]);
```

Instead of:

```
client.getProfile(name, '4').then(
    function(value) { 
        data => pId.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Platform:" + data.profile.platform[1]));
     // ^^^^
     // Remove anonymous function  
        data => pName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name:" + data.profile.displayName));
     // ^^^^
     // Remove anonymous function  
    }
);
```

Do this:

```
client.getProfile(name, '4').then(data => {
  pId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Platform: ${data.profile.platform[1]}`));
  pName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Name: ${data.profile.displayName}`));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your lambda you just defined 2 anonymous functions without the actual execution:

```
   client.getProfile(name, '4').then(
    function(value) { 
        data => pId.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Platform:" + 
          data.profile.platform[1]));
        data => pName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name:" + 
         data.profile.displayName));
    }
   );
```

replace them with actual calls